# Include workspace .log files in "Console Output"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job that executes a "foo.sh" and "bar.sh", and those scripts produce "foo.log", "bar.log" respectively. foo.sh and bar.sh are long running jobs, and I wan't to view their log files unified in the "Console Output" view of jenkins.

I know I can archive these logs as build artifacts, but I want to monitor all 3 logs ("Console Output"/stdout, foo.log and bar.log) from one view - Console Output.

Is there a plugin or configuration option that will let me do this?

---

Note: `foo.sh` and `bar.sh` are obviously placeholders, but I'm afraid they're from a vendor and I cannot modify them to adjust logging behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Assume your files are under `$WORKSPACE`:
`tail -F *.log`

**Edit:**
Or you could consider re-writing your `foo.sh` and `bar.sh`, but instead of redirecting to log file, [**`tee`**](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/tee-command-examples/) to console *and* log file.

`echo "doing stuff" 2>&1|tee -a foo.log`
Above will print to console (which is displayed in Jenkins console output), and redirect to `foo.log`

**Edit 2:**
If you have no control over `foo.sh` and `bar.sh`, you would need a wrapping script to launch them with some trickery.

Basically, after you send `foo.sh` to background (so that we can continue), before you `tail` the log, you need to ensure that `tail` would be killed. We do this by launching another background process to monitor `foo.sh` process and kill `tail` (that is yet to be launched in script). As we haven't launched `tail` yet, we don't really know what its PID would be, hence we refer to it through command line

```
# Send foo.sh to background and record the PID
echo "Launching foo.sh to background"
nohup ./foo.sh &
foo_pid=$!
echo "Foo PID to monitor=$foo_pid"

# Launch a statement that will run ever 3 seconds to monitor status 
# of foo.sh, and if foo.sh finished, then kill a 'future' tail command
echo "Launching tail-killer to background"
nohup $(sleep 3; while kill -0 $foo_pid; do sleep 3; done; kill $(ps --no-heading -C "tail -F foo.log" | awk '{print $1}') ) &

# Tail foo.sh's log
echo "Launching tail to monitor foo.sh"
echo
tail -F foo.log
echo

# Get the return code of foo.sh
wait $foo_pid
echo "Foo.sh returned with $?
```

**Considerations/improvements:**

- The "killer" process is running every 3 seconds. You may want to increase that for performance reasons
- `Foo.sh` could print more than 10 lines after start, before `tail` is called. Use `tail -n` to increase the number of starting lines.
- The "killer" will break if there are multiple `tail -F foo.log` detected. You should modify it to be more robust

Comment: `tail -f` is effectively what I want to do of course, but I could I do that without blocking the build, and how would the `tail -f` know when the build is finished? I don't want to SSH onto the server of course!

Comment: @xconspirisist Edited with `tee` suggestion

Comment: Ah, sorry sir, I didn't state in my original question - I cannot modify the scripts (obviously they're placeholders) to output on stdout (or my problem would be solved!